# Concentration of top eigenvectors

Tags: pca, convergence, covariance-matrix, random-matrix

Let $M$ be a $d \times d$ symmetric matrix with rank $k < d$, write $M = U \Lambda U^T$.

Define $\hat{M} = M + Z$, where $z_{ij} \sim N(0, 1 /n )$. Suppose we try to estimate $U$ by taking the top $k$ eigenvectors $U'$ obtained from applying SVD to $\hat{M}$.

Is there a way to relate $U$ to $U'$ as a function of $n$ e.g bound $\|U - U'\|_{op}$ as some function of $n$?